# How to stop running jobs simultaneously in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written a procedure and in that I am creating one job. And i want that once the 1st job gets completed then it should create the 2nd job. But when i am running my code it is creating both the jobs simultaneously and running the both jobs at same time. Kindly find the code

```
create or replace procedure test_proc

v_count number;
v_text varchar2(15);
v_date varchar2(15);
v_date2 date;
v_status varchar2(15);

begin

execute immediate 'truncate table dataq_support.test_vishal';
select count(*) into v_count from DATAQ_SUPPORT.test_proc_table;
select max(fdate) into v_date from DATAQ_SUPPORT.test_proc_table;

select distinct fpermissions into v_text from DATAQ_SUPPORT.test_proc_table;

select to_date (SUBSTR(v_date,1,6),'MM-DD') into v_date2 from dual;


insert into dataq_support.test_vishal(id,text) values (1,v_date2);
commit;

if v_date2 = to_date('08-SEP-17','DD-MM-YY')
then 
insert into dataq_support.test_vishal(id,text) values (1,'1st if');
commit;
if v_count = 266 
then
insert into dataq_support.test_vishal(id,text) values (2,'2st if');
commit;
if v_text = '-rwxrwxrwx'
then
insert into dataq_support.test_vishal(id,text) values (3,'3st if');
commit;

dbms_scheduler.create_job(
job_name => 'FIRST_JOB',
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
job_action => 
  '
  Begin
  IMPDATA.GEN_IMP.READ_AND_IMPORT_TABLES(''SAP_WITHOUT_BOM'');
  END;',
 start_date => systimestamp,
 enabled => TRUE,
 comments => 'Import job');  

else
insert into dataq_support.test_vishal(id,text) values (3,'else');
commit;
end if;
end if;
else
    insert into dataq_support.test_vishal(id,text) values (4,'Else');
commit;
end if;

insert into dataq_support.test_vishal(id,text) values (5,'ENDING');
commit;

dbms_scheduler.create_job( 
job_name => 'SECOND_JOB', 
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
job_action => '
  begin 
    IMPORT_REFDEV_ANALYSE; 
  end;',
  start_date => systimestamp, 
  comments => 'Rerun Daily Import and Analyze Job', 
  enabled => TRUE
);

EXCEPTION when others
then 
dbms_output.put_line('There is some issue');


end;`
```

Here I have created 1st job as FIRST_JOB. I want that once the FIRST_JOB gets completed then it should create another job namely SECOND_JOB.

Comment: Can't you do so that, the first job, upon completion starts the next one?

Answer (score 2):

`use_current_session` argument of RUN_JOB determines whether a job runs synchronously or asynchronously

The following example **synchronously** runs two jobs:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(
    JOB_NAME            => 'DSS.ETLJOB1, DSS.ETLJOB2',
    USE_CURRENT_SESSION => TRUE);
END;
/
```

This way 2 jobs `DSS.ETLJOB1, DSS.ETLJOB2` are executed sequentially one after another (just like you wanted).